# Исключить определенные символы из строки python?

Tags: python

Допустим есть строка: `20, 8, 5, 19, 21, 14, 19, 5, 20, 19, 5, 20, 19, 1, 20, 20, 23, 5, 12, 22, 5, 15, 3, 12, 15, 3, 11`. Hадо удалить все запятые. Как мне это будет правильнее сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
test = "20, 8, 5, 19, 21, 14, 19, 5, 20, 19, 5, 20, 19, 1, 20, 20, 23, 5, 12, 22, 5, 15, 3, 12, 15, 3, 11"
test = test.replace(",", "")
```

Или так (взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52649163/9245265)), хотя не вижу смысла использовать этот вариант):

```
"".join([x for x in test if x is not ','])
```

Comment: Какая разница между моим ответом и вашим?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica нет разницы между ними, я почти одновременно ответил с вами

Answer (score 0):

```
string = string.replace(',', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот еще вот так (`translate`, `python 2.x`)

```
s.translate(None, ',')
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52649163/9245265)

Python 3.x:

```
s.translate({ord(','): None})
```

Comment: в Python3 такое не работает

Comment: @SKIP И что? А минус за что? Вопрос по метке значит можно любые решения предложить.

Comment: Любое решение хотябы должно работать на текущей версии, нет?)

Comment: @SKIP `Одновременно востребованы две параллельно развивающиеся версии языка Python — 2 и 3. Пожалуйста, используйте дополнительную метку [python-2.7] или [python-3.x], если ваш вопрос ориентирован на конкретную версию.`

Comment: @SKIP И "хотя бы" раздельно.

Comment: @SKIP Это не пожелание, а конструктивная критика. Извините, если обидел, тоже не идеален в орфографии.

Comment: В Python3 работает так: `s.translate({ord(','): None})`

Comment: Или если нужно удалить несколько разных символов: `s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '.,;'))`